# RShiny app failing to connect to SQL Server

Tags: r

I published a shiny app on shiny apps.io but my apps gives a log error of failure to connect to the local SQL Server that runs on my laptop. Any idea on how to correct this? The error messages are as shown below

```
2018-07-03T21:16:34.512687+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: Using pandoc at /opt/connect/ext/pandoc2
2018-07-03T21:16:34.647035+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2018-07-03T21:16:34.512544+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: LANG: en_US.UTF-8
2018-07-03T21:16:34.651834+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: 
2018-07-03T21:16:34.512570+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: R version: 3.5.0
2018-07-03T21:16:34.651837+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: Starting R with process ID: '50'
2018-07-03T21:16:34.512571+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: shiny version: 1.1.0
2018-07-03T21:16:34.677158+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: 
2018-07-03T21:16:34.512571+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: httpuv version: 1.4.3
2018-07-03T21:16:34.677161+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: Listening on http://107.0.0.1:37281
2018-07-03T21:16:34.512572+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: rmarkdown version: NA
2018-07-03T21:16:34.512572+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: knitr version: NA
2018-07-03T21:16:34.512584+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: jsonlite version: 1.5
2018-07-03T21:16:34.512585+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: RJSONIO version: NA
2018-07-03T21:16:34.512588+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: htmltools version: 0.3.6
2018-07-03T21:16:36.889286+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: Loading required package: ggplot2
2018-07-03T21:16:37.243639+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: 
2018-07-03T21:16:37.243642+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: Attaching package: ‘plotly’
2018-07-03T21:16:37.243643+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: 
2018-07-03T21:16:37.244478+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: The following object is masked from ‘package:ggplot2’:
2018-07-03T21:16:37.244480+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: 
2018-07-03T21:16:37.244481+00:00 shinyapps[373157]:     last_plot
2018-07-03T21:16:37.245245+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: 
2018-07-03T21:16:37.244481+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: 
2018-07-03T21:16:37.245244+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:
2018-07-03T21:16:37.245246+00:00 shinyapps[373157]:     filter
2018-07-03T21:16:37.245246+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: 
2018-07-03T21:16:37.245914+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:
2018-07-03T21:16:37.245916+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: 
2018-07-03T21:16:37.245916+00:00 shinyapps[373157]:     layout
2018-07-03T21:16:37.245917+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: 
2018-07-03T21:16:37.258592+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: Warning in odbcDriverConnect("driver=SQL Server; server=WDX5CG7523QD51\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=FTEST") :
2018-07-03T21:16:37.258593+00:00 shinyapps[373157]:   [RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found
2018-07-03T21:16:37.258960+00:00 shinyapps[373157]:   ODBC connection failed
2018-07-03T21:16:37.258958+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: Warning in odbcDriverConnect("driver=SQL Server; server=WDX5CG7523QD51\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=FTEST") :
2018-07-03T21:16:37.259910+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: Warning: Error in odbcClearError: first argument is not an open RODBC channel
2018-07-03T21:16:37.270829+00:00 shinyapps[373157]:   61: stop
2018-07-03T21:16:37.270830+00:00 shinyapps[373157]:   60: odbcClearError
2018-07-03T21:16:37.271006+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: Error in odbcClearError(conn) : 
2018-07-03T21:16:37.270831+00:00 shinyapps[373157]:   59: server [/srv/connect/apps/Desktop/app.R#77]
2018-07-03T21:16:37.271007+00:00 shinyapps[373157]:   first argument is not an open RODBC channel
2018-07-03T21:16:41.805471+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: Warning in odbcDriverConnect("driver=SQL Server; server=WDX5CG7523QD51\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=FTEST") :
2018-07-03T21:16:41.805475+00:00 shinyapps[373157]:   [RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found
2018-07-03T21:16:41.805760+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: Warning in odbcDriverConnect("driver=SQL Server; server=WDX5CG7523QD51\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=FTEST") :
2018-07-03T21:16:41.805761+00:00 shinyapps[373157]:   ODBC connection failed
2018-07-03T21:16:41.806533+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: Warning: Error in odbcClearError: first argument is not an open RODBC channel
2018-07-03T21:16:41.809061+00:00 shinyapps[373157]:   60: odbcClearError
2018-07-03T21:16:41.809062+00:00 shinyapps[373157]:   59: server [/srv/connect/apps/Desktop/app.R#77]
2018-07-03T21:16:41.809240+00:00 shinyapps[373157]: Error in odbcClearError(conn) : 
2018-07-03T21:16:41.809241+00:00 shinyapps[373157]:   first argument is not an open RODBC channel
2018-07-03T21:16:41.809060+00:00 shinyapps[373157]:   61: stop
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something ... you just deployed an app to `shinyapps.io` and expect it to connect to an instance of SQL Server running on your laptop's windows OS? I might be wrong, but `WDX5CG7523QD51` does not resolve to an IP address on my computer (nor would I assume that `shinyapps` has an ODBC connection defined for this case).

Comment: @r2evans- Yes, WDX5CG7523QD51 is my local server name. Is there anyway the shiny app can connect to this database and pull the data it needs to display? If shiny apps does not have an ODBC connection, how  should I bring the data into the Rshiny environment so that the app can be successfully deployed?

Comment: I cannot fathom a way that that could be accomplished robustly or (much more importantly) securely. If you need data available for the app in a db-like format, you might consider deploying a sqlite dataset with it: SQL, same queries (mostly), no network requirements, likely faster, and much more secure.

Comment: How about I pull data into Rstudio and then store it locally as as CSV file. Then bring the csv file into the Rshiny Program and then try?

Comment: Only you know how feasible that is. If it is just one table, then a CSV might be fine. If you expect multiple simultaneous users and load-time of the CSV is at all problematic, then I suggest either [`feather`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/feather/index.html) (faster access, option to only load data on-demand) or re-suggest [`RSQLite`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/index.html). RSQLite is most likely the easiest (esp with 2+ tables), since it'll require the least amount of work in shiny to shift efforts.